# Input shape for 1D convolution network in keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am quite new to keras and I have a problem in understanding shapes.

I wanted to create 1D Conv Keras model as follows, I don't know this is correct or not:

```
TIME_PERIODS = 511
num_sensors = 2
num_classes = 4
BATCH_SIZE = 400
EPOCHS = 50
model_m = Sequential()
model_m.add(Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu', input_shape=(TIME_PERIODS, num_sensors)))
model_m.add(Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu'))
model_m.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model_m.add(Conv1D(160, 10, activation='relu'))
model_m.add(Conv1D(160, 10, activation='relu'))
model_m.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model_m.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_m.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

The input data I have is 888 different panda data frame where each frame is of shape (511, 3) where 511 is numbers of signal points and 0th column is sensor1 values, 1st column is sensor2 values and 2nd column is labelled signals.

Now how I should combine all my 888 different panda data frame so I have x_train and y_train from X and Y using  Sklearn train_test_split.

Also, I think the input shape I am defining for the model is wrong and I don't think I actually have TIME_PERIODS because, for 1-time point, I have 2 sensor inputs (**orange, blue** line) value and 1 output label (**green** line).

[image]

The context of the problem I am trying to solve e.g.
 input: time-based 2 sensors values say for 1 AM-2 AM hour from a user, output: the range of times e.g where the user was doing activity 1, activity 2, activity X on 1:10-1:15, 1:15-1:30, 1:30-2:00, The above plot show a sample training input and output.

The problem is inspired from [here](https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf) but in my case, I don't have any time period, my 1-time point has 1 output label.

Update 1:
I am almost certain that my TIME_PERIODS=1 as for the prediction I will give 511 inputs and expects to get 511 output values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each dataframe is an independent sequence?

```
 fileNames = get a list of filenames here, you can maybe os.listdir for that
 allFrames = [pandas.read_csv(filename,... other_things...).values for filename in fileNames]


 allData = np.stack(allFrames, axis=0)
 inputData = allData[:,:num_sensors]
 outputData = allData[:, -1:]
```

You can now use train test split the way you want. 
Your input shape is correct.

---

If you want to predict the whole sequence, then you have to remove the poolings. Every convolution should use `padding='same'`.

And maybe you should use a `Biridectional(LSTM(units, return_sequences=True))` layer somewhere to make your model stronger.

---

A simple model as an example. (Notice that models are totally open to creativity)

```
from keras.layers import *

inputs = Input((TIME_PERIODS,num_sensors)) #Should be called "time_steps" to be precise
outputs = Conv1D(any, 3, padding='same', activation = 'tanh')(inputs)
outputs = Bidirectional(LSTM(any, return_sequences=True))(outputs)
outputs = Conv1D(num_classes, activation='softmax', padding='same')(outputs)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: I don't think the shape is correct. I have 4 output classes and I want to find out the prediction class of each of the 511 points similar to my plot picture. Think of 511 as time ticks.

Comment: Then remove poolings, use always `padding='same'`. And maybe switch to recurrent networks.

Comment: could you provide a very simple model about what you said. What is the input shape to first 1DConv layer?

Comment: There it is, a simple model mixing Conv and LSTM

Answer (score 0):

To say the least, you're in the correct path. The full solution for this would be like,

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fname, index_col=<int>, header=<int>) for f filenames], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

inputs = df.loc[:,:-1]
labels = df.loc[:,0]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inputs, labels, test_size=<float>)
```

To add a bit more information, note how you are doing,

```
model_m.add(Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu', input_shape=(TIME_PERIODS, num_sensors)))
```

and not

```
model_m.add(Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu', padding='SAME', input_shape=(TIME_PERIODS, num_sensors)))
```

So, as you're not setting `padding="Same"` for the convolution layers this might have the undesirable effect of input becoming smaller and smaller as you go deeper to the model. If that's what you need, that's okay. Otherwise, set `padding="SAME".

For example, without same-padding you'll get, a width around `144` when you get to the `GlobalPooling` layer, where if you use same-padding it would be roughly `170`. It's not a major problem here, but can easily lead to negative sizes in your input for deeper layers.

Comment: I don't think the shape is correct. I have 4 output classes and I want to find out the prediction class of each of the 511 points similar to my plot picture. Think of 511 as time ticks.

Comment: @RoshanMehta Then you probably be modelling this as a time-series problem (i.e. use LSTMs). Why did you use convolution filters in the first place?

Comment: Because I read about human activity recognition using CNNs and it works very well but in those problem, there is timeperiod  which correspondence to one label but in my case I don't actually have any timeperiod. I have 2 input and want one output.

Comment: Can you share the paper/resource you saw this on? In my experience deep learning based activity recognition is always done with some LSTM/RNN component on it (e.g. LSTM / ConvLSTM)

Comment: https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf